# How in PhpStorm keep list of all modified files?

Tags: phpstorm

Using search in PhpStorm 2019.2.3 I if there is a way to keep list of all modified files with possibility
to check for my modifications ? Usually I do it with git, but this php/laravel project does not use git...

Thanks!

Comment: You can try **Local History**. It's not a replacement, but is good enough for recent **local** changes: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/local-history.html

Comment: Yes, I know how Local History works. But firstly I need to keep list of files I modified. Say working last 2 days I modified 10 files among many files of the project. How can I got listing of these 10 files ?

Comment: Invoke Local History on the project root and go from there: if you click on a change it will show a list of modified files: https://postimg.cc/4Y2WdZ87 . There is a video at the bottom of the JetBrains help page (link in my first comment) -- have a look at what it can do and if it's suitable for your needs.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like what I need. Also I see that modifications of storage/logs files is also in this  list. How can I exclude  storage/logs  from this listing?

Comment: Mark such folder(s) as excluded I guess.

Comment: Thanks, it works, though to track listing with any saving  and write manually listing of modified files seems not very convinient. Are there some tools/external plugin to keep all modified files in one listing from some period of time?